# How to add colour matched legend to a R matplot

Tags: r, plot

I plot several lines on a graph using matplot:

```
matplot(cumsum(as.data.frame(daily.pnl)),type="l")
```

This gives me default colours for each line - which is fine,

But I now want to add a legend that reflects those same colours - how can I achieve that?

PLEASE NOTE - I am trying NOT to specify the colours to matplot in the first place.

```
legend(0,0,legend=spot.names,lty=1)
```

Gives me all the same colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default color parameter to matplot is a sequence over the nbr of column of your data.frame. So you can add legend like this :

```
nn <- ncol(daily.pnl)
legend("top", colnames(daily.pnl),col=seq_len(nn),cex=0.8,fill=seq_len(nn))
```

Using `cars` data set as example, here the complete code to add a legend. Better to use `layout` to add the legend in a pretty manner.

```
daily.pnl <- cars
nn <- ncol(daily.pnl)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1), width=c(4,1)) 
par(mar=c(5,4,4,0)) #No margin on the right side
matplot(cumsum(as.data.frame(daily.pnl)),type="l")
par(mar=c(5,0,4,2)) #No margin on the left side
plot(c(0,1),type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
legend("center", colnames(daily.pnl),col=seq_len(nn),cex=0.8,fill=seq_len(nn))
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work, matplot changes line types as well and these are not shown

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to reproduce what you are looking for using the iris dataset. I get the plot with the following expression:

```
matplot(cumsum(iris[,1:4]), type = "l")
```

Then, to add a legend, you can specify the default lines colour and type, i.e., numbers 1:4 as follows:

```
legend(0, 800, legend = colnames(iris)[1:4], col = 1:4, lty = 1:4)
```

Now you have the same in the legend and in the plot. Note that you might need to change the coordinates for the legend accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I like the @agstudy's trick to have a nice legend.

For the sake of comparison, I took @agstudy's example and plotted it with `ggplot2`:

- The first step is to "melt" the data-set

  ```
  require(reshape2)
  df <- data.frame(x=1:nrow(cars), cumsum(data.frame(cars)))
  df.melted <- melt(df, id="x")
  ```
- The second step looks rather simple in comparison to the solution with `matplot`

  ```
  require(ggplot2)
  qplot(x=x, y=value, color=variable, data=df.melted, geom="line")
  ```

[image]

Comment: maybe it is better to add `theme_bw` here.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly @agstudy solution does the trick, but only for n ≤ 6

Here we have a matrix with 8 columns. The colour of the first 6 labels are correct.
The 7th and 8th are wrong. The colour in the plots restarts from the beginning (black, red ...) , whereas in the label it continues (yellow, grey, ...)

Still haven't figured out why this is the case. I'll maybe update this post with my findings.

```
matplot(x = lambda, y = t(ridge$coef), type = "l", main="Ridge regression", xlab="λ", ylab="Coefficient-value", log = "x")
nr = nrow(ridge$coef)
legend("topright", rownames(ridge$coef), col=seq_len(nr), cex=0.8, lty=seq_len(nr), lwd=2)
```

[image: Example Image with more than 6 features]

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that `matplot` uses linetypes 1:5 and colors 1:6 to establish the appearance of the lines. If you want to create a legend try the following approach:

```
## Plot multiple columns of the data frame 'GW' with matplot
cstart = 10           # from column 
cend = cstart + 20    # to column 
nr <- cstart:cend
ltyp <- rep(1:5, times=length(nr)/5, each=1) # the line types matplot uses
cols <- rep(1:6, times=length(nr)/6, each=1) # the cols matplot uses 

matplot(x,GW[,nr],type='l')
legend("bottomright", as.character(nr), col=cols, cex=0.8, lty=ltyp, ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65790207/6574038) is fantastic, but we can have that cheaper by exploiting recycling.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))   

matplot(M, type='l')  ## w/o explicit specification of colors or lines

matplot(M, type='l', lty=1:5, col=1:6)  ## w/ specification to proof equivalence
legend('topleft', lty=1:5, col=1:6, some_labels)  ## using in legend

par(op)
```

[image]

This way we can get 5*6 = 30 well distinguishable professional looking lines.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
M <- replicate(10, sort(rnorm(100) + rexp(100)))
some_labels <- sprintf('<label %02d>', seq_len(ncol(M)))
```